# Prove that there is a base in $R^n$ that matches criteria

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, linear-transformations

The question is

> let $T:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ be a linear transformation such that $T(T(v)) = 2T(v)$
> Prove there is a $B$ such that $[T]_B$ is diagonal and that in the main diagonal  there are only $2$'s and $0$'s

How do I prove such thing? Could not find any base that matches the criteria. thought about
$B = \{(-2), (1,1), (-2, -2, -2), (1,1,1,1),\dots\}$
But this is not necessarily valid from every liner transformation that matches the criteria

Comment: Your set $B$ has elements from different $\Bbb R^n$'s, it doesn't make sense for this problem. See answer below for a clean(er) argument.

Comment: @IvoTerek I don't understand your solution. we didn't learn about  minimal polynomials or the notation cT(t)

Comment: Then I don't know how you're expected to solve the problem. The theorem saying that an operator $T$ is diagonalizable if and only if its minimal polynomial splits is the main tool when you can't do direct computations. Also $c_T(t)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $T$ (I explicitly wrote this in the answer) -- different texts/people might use slightly different notations for this, but it doesn't matter (what matters is what the polynomial means).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we show Im $T$ $\cap$ Ker $T = 0$.

Let $w \in$ Im $T$ $\cap$ Ker $T$. Then $w = T(v) \implies 0 = T(w) = T(T(v)) = 2T(v) = 2w \implies w = 0$.

Now we can let $B = (v_1,...,v_k, T(v_{k+1}),...,T(v_n))$ be our basis, where $(v_1,...,v_k)$ is a basis for Ker $T$ and $(T(v_{k+1}),...,T(v_n))$ is a basis for Im $T$.

It is straightforward to verify that $[T]_B$ satisfies your condition.

Comment: But you are not gunteed to  have [T]B have a diagnal of zeros and twos

Comment: The columns of $[T]_B$ are $(T(v_1),...,T(v_k),T(T(v_{k+1})),...,T(T(v_n))) = (0,...,0,2T(v_{k+1}),...,2T(v_n))$. Write those columns relative to the basis $B$.

Answer (score 0):

The relation $T(T(v))=2T(v)$ says that the polynomial $t^2-2t = t(t-2)$ annihilates $T$. So the minimal polynomial $m_T(t)$ divides $t(t-2)$. This means that the minimal polynomial is $t$, $t-2$ or $t(t-2)$. All of them are irreducible, so $T$ is diagonalizable in any case. And the characteristic polynomial is $c_T(t) = t^i(t-2)^j$, where $i,j\geq 0$ and $i+j=n$. The possible roots are $0$ and $2$ (and at most one of them might not occur if $i=0$ or $j=0$ -- unless $n=0$, in which case $T=0$ and there's nothing to do).